# Problem Installing Ubuntu on Alienware m14xr1 (GRUB Loading. Welcome to GRUB!)

Tags: grub2, system-installation, alienware

Trying to install the latest Ubuntu (22.04.1 LTS) onto my old Alienware M14xR1 laptop.  Can't reach the installation setup.

Followed the guide (https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview), even looked through a few Youtube install videos.

When I boot from USB flash drive, I get a message of "GRUB Loading.  Welcome to Grub!"  It looks like it's loading, but it's unresponsive.

Ways that I've tried to trouble shoot:

-I've tried using both balenaEtcher and RUFUS to create the bootable USB stick.  Same message

-F12, boot options.  There is no option to disable secure boot.  All I see is boot device priority.  (Updated bios from dell.  There doesn't seem to be any changes.)

I dunno what else to do... I've tried with the original hard drive, and swapping it for a new ssd.

Any advice?  Thanks!

(Goal is to ultimately get retropie running on it, so that I can gift to a cousin.)

Comment: F12 is the one-time boot menu / boot override menu. You won't find any UEFI settings there, that would be nonsensical. You need to actually open the UEFI settings and maybe do a few changes. Yes, you can disable Secure Boot and make it easier to install and use Nvidia graphics drivers but in itself SB has nothing to do with booting the live session/installation. First you need to verify the ISO and download it again if it must be. Balena Etcher is fine and foll-proof IF the ISO isn't corrupt. Then open UEFI settings and assure CSM/Legacy/"BIOS" is disabled.

Comment: If nVidia you will need to use Safe Graphic & choose to install restricted drivers to get nVidia driver correctly installed as part of install. Older post with newer model. May have some similar issues. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2311390&page=2&p=13430555#post13430555 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085884/install-ubuntu-on-alienware-15-r4